# Release all Keys when test is completed Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a number of tests that I'm running with Selenium. I'm using short cut keys for a number of my tests. Sometimes the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> key stay pressed. Is there a way I can release these keys at the end of each test?

I tried at the end of my test

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.KeyUp(Keys.Ctrl);
 action.KeyUp(Keys.Alt);
 action.KeyUp(Keys.Shift);
```

However this does not release these toggle keys.

Comment: Why don't you release the key as soon as you use it in your code?

Comment: I have tried doing this like so `action.SendKeys(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys(Keys.Tab).KeyUp(Keys.Control).KeyUp(Keys.Alt).Perform();` and then `var typeInto = excelSession.FindElementByName("A1");
            typeInto.SendKeys(Keys.Alt + "CFNC");` however sometimes this works when I run it and sometime the keys stick